# Running an ember controller function when route loads to set property that controls a checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, ember.js

I have set up an ember checkbox:

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding='isChecked'}}
```

This checkbox is bound to this controller:

```
App.SettingsController = Ember.Controller.extend({

isChecked: false,
isItChecked: function(){

    var me = this;
    $.getJSON('ajax/checkIfUseLowRes.php', function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        //me.isChecked = data;
        me.set('isChecked', data);
        //console.log(me.isChecked);

    })

},
sendSetting: function(){

    var isChecked = this.isChecked;
    //this.set('isChecked', !isChecked);
    console.log(isChecked);

    $.post('ajax/setLowRes.php', {useLowRes: isChecked});
    App.nameSpace.set('needsRefresh', true);

}.observes('isChecked')


});
```

Essentially it is a checkbox which posts a setting, my problem is setting the original state of the checkbox. When I load the route, I want to have `isItChecked()` run to set the checkbox's original state.

Example: 
1. I go in to settings, click the checkbox
2. I leave the site and come back to the settings page
Here is where I want the `isItChecked()` function to run to query the server and see if the setting is set

If it is set, the get request returns true, I want the checkbox to be checked, hence setting me.isChecked to data (true)

as of right now I can't figure out how to do this, can anyone help me?

I've tried setting it in my `App.SettingsRoute`'s model, but that doesn't seem to be able to run the function in my controller.

Thanks.

JSBin:http://jsbin.com/ukuwiq/1/edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by using the route's setupController method.

```
App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    $.getJSON('ajax/checkIfUseLowRes.php', function(data){
      console.log('setting isChecked to: ', data);
      controller.set('isChecked', data);
    })
  }
})
```

This should get the job done with the fewest changes to your existing code but does have some drawbacks and is not exactly *the-ember-way*. Probably it would make more sense to have a model object that represents your settings, move ajax code to that model object and use the route's model hook to trigger as needed. See [ember-without-ember-data](http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html) for an example of how that can work.

Answer (score 6):

as Mike says, you can use 'setupController' or you could also use this:

```
App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  activate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('settings').isItChecked();
  }
})
```

Comment: should it not rather be `this.controllerFor('settings').send('isItChecked');`?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use the init function? e.g.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function() {
    console.log("function run");
},
```

Comment: This will only execute once, not every time the controller is shown.